# Rails - Add prompt to country_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, form-helpers

As title suggests, how do I add a prompt using [country_select gem](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select)?

Currently just to try get it working I tried

```
<%= f.country_select(:country, { prompt: 'Please select..' }, {prompt: 'Please select..'}, {prompt: 'Please select..'} ) %>
```

Comment: Updated.. Trying to pass it into any hash to see if one accepts it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd is a option argument in country_select helper so,

```
<%= f.country_select(:country, your_options_method, {prompt: 'Please select..'}) %>
```